# How to call hoarders in Russian?

Tags: перевод

Yesterday I've learned about a fascinating (and really depressing) psychological phenomenon which is called ["compulsive hoarding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_hoarding). The Russian article about this phenomenon is called "Патологическое накопительство".

The thing is that, however, for the term hoarder (that is, a person with such disorder) it's more difficult to find exact Russian counterpart. For instance, Плюшкин is more close to just unsystematic collector, and "барахольщик" is also something yet related though quite different.

My question would be - what is the closest term to English hoarder we can come with in Russian?

Comment: It looks like _барахольщик_ is just the word you're looking for.

Comment: «Жертва вещизма »

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, both "плюшкин" and "барахольшик" is used for both really ill people and people with borderline hoarding behaviour. I.e. their homes don't look like a total mess, but they definitely have problems with getting rid of unused or broken stuff.

I don't think there a  term for real compulsive hoarders in Russian language.

You could use something like "патологический барахольщик" if you need to specify the level of the problem.

Comment: Я б уж тогда сказал «патологический» а не безумный)

Comment: @shabunc да, так даже лучше. Пойду поправлю.

Answer (score 2):

I think the translation of compulsive hoarder would be:

```
человек, страдающий патологическим накопительством
```

Other words like гобсек reveal negative attitude and no mentioning of the illness.

Answer (score 1):

«Скопидом» is quite close to intended meaning, though it is a bit archaic and may also be used in positive light.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, мне кажется, что предложенные варианты выглядят сильно коряво.

Плюшкин - да, собирает всякий хлам, но он из него что-то мастерит.

Барахольщик - продавец барахла на барахолке.

Остальные варианты - шуточные или совершенно нелепые фразы - так никто не говорит.

Есть, пусть и явно выражающий негативное отношение к таким людям, но более нативный, вариант:

Шурешки - это любые мелкие детали и объекты не несущие прямой смысловой нагрузки.

Hoarder = ШУРЕШЕЧНИК - человек, собирающий всякий хлам с помоек и приносящий это в дом/квартиру.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please back your answer by some kind of reference or a link to the usage of this word in the meaning you are suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D1%88%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant usages by any of your links. It would be better if your copied and pasted the relevant part of the page you're trying to link to in your answer, so that the future visitors of this site would not have to go through all of them. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I tend to use the word хламщик.

Incidentally, back in the USSR, hoarding was not a disorder, but a survival strategy.